# Printing Android property_get calls in logcat

Tags: android, c++, c

I'm having difficulty getting certain types of requests in Android for system property keys to print in the Android logcat, despite trying a number of different approaches.

`__android_log_print()` works well to show requests for system property keys obtained using `SystemProperties_getSS` (in ./frameworks/base/core/jni/android_os_SystemProperties.cpp):

```
static jstring SystemProperties_getSS(JNIEnv *env, jobject clazz,
                                      jstring keyJ, jstring defJ)
{
    int len;
    const char* key;
    char buf[PROPERTY_VALUE_MAX];
    jstring rvJ = NULL;

    if (keyJ == NULL ) {
        jniThrowNullPointerException(env, "key must not be null.");
        goto error;
    }

    key = env->GetStringUTFChars(keyJ, NULL);

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "KB", "Key = %s", key);

    len = property_get(key, buf, "");
    if ((len <= 0) && (defJ != NULL)) {
        rvJ = defJ;
    } else if (len >= 0) {
        rvJ = env->NewStringUTF(buf);
    } else {
        rvJ = env->NewStringUTF("");
    }

    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(keyJ, key);
error:
    return rvJ;
}
```

This displays correctly in the logcat any keys obtained using this function, eg:

```
03-16 22:28:24.679: D/KB(2792): Key = events.cpu
03-16 22:28:24.689: D/KB(3101): Key = debug.hwui.disable_vsync
03-16 22:28:24.689: D/KB(3101): Key = debug.hwui.profile
03-16 22:28:24.689: D/KB(3101): Key = debug.hwui.show_dirty_regions
03-16 22:28:26.829: D/KB(3101): Key = viewancestor.profile_rendering
03-16 22:28:26.829: D/KB(3101): Key = debug.hwui.disable_vsync
03-16 22:28:26.829: D/KB(3101): Key = debug.hwui.profile
03-16 22:28:26.829: D/KB(3101): Key = debug.hwui.show_dirty_regions
03-16 22:28:28.249: D/KB(2792): Key = debug.freemem
```

When I try to do the same type of debugging in other parts of the code, however, I can't get anything to print in the logcat. For example, using `ALOGE()` (in this case, in ./system/core/libcutils/properties.c) yields no output in the logcat:

```
int property_get(const char *key, char *value, const char *default_value)
{
    int len;

    ALOGE("GETPROP Key [%s]\n", key);

    len = __system_property_get(key, value);
    if(len > 0) {
        return len;
    }

    if(default_value) {
        len = strlen(default_value);
        memcpy(value, default_value, len + 1);
    }
    return len;
}
```

Same goes for ./system/core/toolbox/getprop.c:

```
int getprop_main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n = 0;

    if (argc == 1) {
        list_properties();
    } else {
        char value[PROPERTY_VALUE_MAX];
        char *default_value;
        if(argc > 2) {
            default_value = argv[2];
        } else {
            default_value = "";
        }

    ALOGE("GETPROP Key [%s]\n", argv[1]);

        property_get(argv[1], value, default_value);
        printf("%s\n", value);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above code compiles correctly and runs, but shows no output in logcat. I've also tried redirecting `stdio` from /dev/null to the ADB shell (as suggested on the Android developer site, using `adb shell setprop log.redirect-stdio true`) to no effect.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps those macros are getting nullified by the platform build system (which is *not* the same as the NDK).  I believe the redirect capability only applies to DVM based programs inheriting from zygote, not standalone executable tools.

Comment: I'm going to answer my own question here (with thanks to Chris Stratton for pointing me in the right direction). I reverted to using `printf` statements, which in conjunction with the `setprop` command to redirect `stdio` was enough to get the output into logcat.